# Knockout validationMessage appears as [object Object]

Tags: html, typescript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Using Knockout, I want to control where the validation message appears on the screen. When I do, instead of the message text showing up, the message displays [object Object]. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputValue" class="form-control form-control-xs data-bind="validationElement: val""
                       data-bind="event: { keyup: maskNumber(event) }"
                       placeholder="Enter Secret Number"
                       />

<p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: val"></p>


@*hidden input to store field to store real value*@
<span >
      "<input id="realInputValue" type="hidden" data-bind="validationOptions: {insertMessages: false}, value: val" />
</span>
```

**TS**

```
this.val.extend(
            {
                maxLength: 5,
                minLength: 5,
                required: { message: 'This number is required' },
                pattern: {
                    params: /^\d+$/,
                    message: 'Please enter only numeric digits'
                }
            });
```

I want the error message for the hidden input field on the bottom to appear underneath the visible input field at the top.

The maskNumber function turns each digit in the inputValue field into an asterisk(*), after storing the actual digit in the hidden "realInputValue" field.

I've looked at [this example](http://embed.plnkr.co/YczQzE/preview) and used [the documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) as well as other resources but no matter what I try, I keep seeing the error message as [object Object] when I try to use validationMessage. When I don't use validationMessage and let the error message go to its default placement, I can see the text of the error message just fine.

How can I make the actual message appear instead of [object Object]?

Comment: What's your input that it's validating? What validation rule is being triggered? Do you have any custom rules defined? Have you changed any of the default messages?

Comment: part of the problem maybe the duplicate `data-bind=` attributes on the first input field

Comment: I would suggest doing a JSON.stringify on the validation object to see what's in it, you are most likely just printing an object instead of a value inside it. Also as Nathan said, you have duplicated `data-bind` in first input which is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @JeffMercado I've included the .ts file that has the validation rules and custom messages. The input is simply any digits that user may type into the field. The .ts code is the extent of the custom rules and messages that I use

Comment: @NathanFisher I removed the duplicate `data-bind` on the input and I still get the [object Object]. However the input is inside of a div that has `data-bind="validationElement: val"`. I removed the data-bind in the div and the issue persisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking deep in the code, I found the issue. The paragraph including the error message should NOT be `<p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: val"></p>`.

Instead it should be `<p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationText: val"></p>`.

In essence, you need to use `validationText` instead of `validationMessage`. I had not found this anywhere in the documentation. Hopefully this helps someone.